# Find $\varlimsup_{x \rightarrow + \infty} (\cos\sqrt{x-2015}-\cos\sqrt{x+2015})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, limits

Find $$\varlimsup_{x \rightarrow + \infty} (\cos\sqrt{x-2015}-\cos\sqrt{x+2015})$$

I don't understand what the overline means. I think about upper limit of the sequence, but I'm not sure that's right for function.
Thank you.

Comment: The limit superior, I guess (although the code is not you you typed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's right for functions. You can find the definition there https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Upper_and_lower_limits It's very natural:

Let $f$ be defined on $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ and there exists a sequence $\{y_n\} \subset E$ converging to $x_0$ (i.e. $x_0 \in \overline{E\setminus \{x_0\}}$. Then
$$
\overline{\lim_{x \to x_0}}f(x) = \inf_{\varepsilon>0} \sup\{f(x) : 0 <|x-x_0| < \varepsilon, \, x \in E\}.
$$

When $x_0 = +\infty$, we have a definition
$$
\overline{\lim_{x \to +\infty}}f(x) = \inf_{r>0} \sup\{f(x) : r < x, \, x \in E\},
$$
which is correct if there exists a sequence $\{y_n\} \subset E$ s.t. $y_n \to +\infty$ when $n \to \infty$. For $x_0 = -\infty$ we have analogous definition.